# How to deactivate a method for a specific menuItem?

Tags: java, swing

I want to check somehow which MenuItem was selected, so that for some menu buttons to draw a grid in a different way.

I have the menu created in the package view, in the class MainUI:

### *Also I have forgot to mention that the code for creating the menu is in a method called **showContainers***

```
        // Create the game menu
    menuGame = new JMenu( "Game" );
    menuGame.setMnemonic( 'G' );
    menuBar.add( menuGame );
    // Create the game menu
    // Build a game menu items
            //...Create 3x3 Game
    menuGame3 = CreateMenuItem( menuGame, ITEM_RADIO,
                            "Create 3x3 Game", null, '3', null );
    //...Create 4x4 Game
    menuGame4 = CreateMenuItem( menuGame, ITEM_RADIO,
                            "Create 4x4 Game", null, '4', null );
            //...Create 5x5 Game
    menuGame5 = CreateMenuItem( menuGame, ITEM_RADIO,
                            "Create 5x5 Game", null, '5', null );
    //...Create 6x6 Game
    menuGame6 = CreateMenuItem( menuGame, ITEM_RADIO,
                            "Create 6x6 Game", null, '6', null );
            //...Create 7x7 Game
    menuGame7 = CreateMenuItem( menuGame, ITEM_RADIO,
                            "Create 7x7 Game", null, '7', null );
            //...Create 8x8 Game
    menuGame8 = CreateMenuItem( menuGame, ITEM_RADIO,
                            "Create 8x8 Game", null, '8', null );
            //...Create 9x9 Game
    menuGame9 = CreateMenuItem( menuGame, ITEM_RADIO,
                            "Create 9x9 Game", null, '9', null );
            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            group.add(menuGame3);
            group.add(menuGame4);
            group.add(menuGame5);
            group.add(menuGame6);
            group.add(menuGame7);
            group.add(menuGame8);
            group.add(menuGame9);

        public void addCreateGame3Listener(ActionListener createGameListener){
    menuGame3.addActionListener(createGameListener);
}

public void addCreateGame4Listener(ActionListener createGameListener){
    menuGame4.addActionListener(createGameListener);
}

    public void addCreateGame5Listener(ActionListener createGameListener){
    menuGame5.addActionListener(createGameListener);
}

public void addCreateGame6Listener(ActionListener createGameListener){
    menuGame6.addActionListener(createGameListener);
}

    public void addCreateGame7Listener(ActionListener createGameListener){
    menuGame7.addActionListener(createGameListener);
}

    public void addCreateGame8Listener(ActionListener createGameListener){
    menuGame8.addActionListener(createGameListener);
}

    public void addCreateGame9Listener(ActionListener createGameListener){
    menuGame9.addActionListener(createGameListener);
}
```

This is the painComponent in GameUI where I did the modifications:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    highLightCage =false ;
    super.paintComponent(g); //clear the off-screen bitmap
    drawCells(g);
    drawCages(g);
            if( MainUI.menuGame3.isSelected()){
                    drawCageLabels(g);
            }
    drawLabels(g);
    drawGameHint(g);
}
```

The Problem was that i didn't declared menuGame3 as public static in the MainUI class and I couldn't reference to him.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: This: `non-static variable menuGame8 cannot be referenced from a static context non-static variable menuGame9 cannot be referenced from a static context` means that you're trying to use instance variables or methods in a static way, probably here: `MainUI.menuGame8.isSelected()`. Solution: don't do that. Use references to actual instances here, not the class name.

Comment: I tried so many things, but can't seem to make it work ... and also don't really know what u mean by "Use references to actual instances here".

Comment: cross-post: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/45232-deactivate-some-methods-some-radiobuttons.html

Answer (score 1):

look into actionListeners and see this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton)

Comment: I've already read that tutorial but couldn't do it for my code :(

Answer (score 1):

Given incomplete code (what does `CreateMenuItem` do?), I'm not sure I can suggest a great solution.  But I assume you have a bunch of `JRadioButton`s, in which case you can do something like this:

```
if ( !menuGame8.isSelected() && !menuGame9.isSelected() ) {
   drawCageLabels();
}
```

Comment: I edited the main post, and added the code for the method you asked and detailed what error I get when I try using that code